# Unable to Remove Style (i.e. Caption) from TOC Options

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using MS Word for Mac Ver 16.15
When generating the TOC, the Style Caption and HDR 1.0 Front Matter can not be removed.  I choose the Options, go to the list of available styles, and clear the number in the TOC level next to the style.  I click OK, and it's still in the list to generate the TOC.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yYs3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Styles Pane, one at a time, locate those styles and choose Modify.

Then from the Modify Styles dialog, choose the Format > Paragraph option.

From the Paragraph dialog change the Outline Level setting to Body Text.

OK your way back.

[image]

Comment: @Barb Good, those two styles should never have had an Outline level assigned to them. How about marking the question as answered.